# NodeJS Express/Mongoose route confusion

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I must not be understanding something correctly here. My route looks like this

```
function(req,res){
      var thingId = validate.thingId(req.body) ? req.body.thingId  : res.send(400,'Invalid Thing');

      var newBlock = new Block({
           thing : mongoose.Types.ObjectId(thingId)
      }).save();
 }
```

I am passing in an empty string in req.body.thingId to test the validation function. It return false as it should, the server returns the 400 error as it should, but I am getting the error
"Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters." (it's talking about the model id).

So obviously newBlock is still being created and thingId is being passed into the mongoose.Types.ObjectId function.

I was under the (probably wrong) impression that calling res.send would essentially be like 'return' and code after it would not run. I can't see how this could be an async problem, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that res.send() does not return execution from the function. You should use a code block and return if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

I did what user3334561 said and this worked.

```
   var thingId;

   if (validate.thingId(req.body)) thingId = req.body.thingId;
   else return res.send(400,'Invalid Thing');
```